# Angular 5 : Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic after installing ng-block-ui

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Im trying to use ng-block-ui (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-block-ui) for my Angular 5 webappp, post installation when I start any application I'm greeted with this

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng-block-ui/block-ui.module.d.ts(8,49): error TS2315: Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

Failed to compile
```

I found articles similar to 'Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic' error for version mismatch (usual suspect) but not sure for this npm module which version should I be using with Angular 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

The 9th version of angular makes `ModuleWithProviders` Generic By Default and you must provide the Type to it.

I think the version of `ng-block-ui` you are trying to use is based on ng 9 or greater.

Try to install the `ng-block-ui` version compatible with ng 5 version that you are using. I would say versions <3 would work as they were published a year ago and ng9 was not released yet.

https://github.com/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui/blob/594eae6a2598e052d5f7be1ddeb4764224c58e70/dev/package.json

Answer (score 0):

I agree with OP. Just to add detail
ModuleWithProviders after the upgrade from Angular 9+ requires strongly types by default now:

```
ModuleWithProviders<T>
```

[ModuleWithProviders Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers)

[Documentation for Angular upgrades](https://update.angular.io/)